# Python: Pinging a URL multiple times at once for testing

Tags: python

I have a link that I want to test for robustness, for lack of a better word. What I have code that pings the URL multiple times, sequentially:

```
# Testing for robustness
for i in range(100000):
    city = 'New York'
    city = '%20'.join(city.split(' '))

    res = requests.get(f'http://example.com/twofishes?query={city}')

    data = res.json()
    geo = data['interpretations'][0]['feature']['geometry']['center']
    print('pinging xtime: %s ' % str(i))
    print(geo['lat'], geo['lng'])
```

I want to take this code, but ping the link say, 10 or 12 times at once. I don't mind the sequential pinging, but that's not as efficient as pinging multiple times at once. I feel like this is a quick modification, where the `for` loop comes out and a `PULL` function goes in?

Comment: There are many ways to tackle this problem. Depending on where you are going to go with this project in the future you may want to consider threading, with some kind of synchronization if you need the pings to be at approximately the same time. In any case, if this is not your website, I would be careful about pinging them (en bulk), because you may get your ip blocked.

Comment: Definitely thinking threading - and warning received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example program which should work for this task. Given that I do not want to be blacklisted, I have not actually tested the code to see if it works. Regardless, it should at least be in the ballpark of what your looking for. If you want actually have all of the threads execute at the same time I would look into adding [events](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#event-objects). Hope this helps.

**Code**

```
import threading
import requests
import requests.exceptions as exceptions


def stress_test(s):
    for i in range(100000):
        try:
            city = 'New York'
            city = '%20'.join(city.split(' '))

            res = s.get(f'http://example.com/twofishes?query={city}')

            data = res.json()
            geo = data['interpretations'][0]['feature']['geometry']['center']
            print('pinging xtime: %s ' % str(i))
            print(geo['lat'], geo['lng'])
        except (exceptions.ConnectionError, exceptions.HTTPError, exceptions.Timeout):
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 12):
        s = requests.session()
        t = threading.Thread(target=stress_test, args=(s,))
        t.start()

    for th in threading.enumerate():
        if th != threading.current_thread():
            th.join()
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. When I run this, it gives the wrong `lat` and `lng` - not NYC like in the example. Any idea of why that might be so? Appreciate the quick answer!

Comment: Ah, I took out the `f` in front of the link. My mistake